# After ET Package Upgrade we see error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

We have recently upgraded to the latest version on ET. After this, while we are Moving the code from one environment to other we see thee below error.

We have successfully compiled all the classes before moving the code.

Following error occurred:

> line 9, column 5: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: et4ae5.triggerutility: line -1, column -1: et4ae5.triggerUtility: line 1, column 24: null 
>   Stack Trace: null

Comment: Did you find the error ? It sounds like a simple apex trigger (and test class?), might need to be updated ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by changing the Salesforce-API version of the concerned apex trigger to 39.0.